# Reporting Services 2005 - How to embed a watermark?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, watermark

In one of our systems that uses Reporting Services 2005, the client is asking for reports to feature a watermark to ensure that reports which are printed out by the customer and sent in (example: A contract document generated by the system but then must be signed and mailed in) are authentic.

I have not been able to find a clear-cut way of doing this. If anybody has any suggestions on how to do easy image watermarking on a report, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a very faded out version of the photo I wanted, making it the same size as an entire piece of paper in terms of dimensions,and then set it as the background image on my report. Not ideal, but oh well.

Comment: How to set background image??